# How to convert IplImage to a GLubyte array?

Tags: opengl, opencv

I have a function that reads a image and does some image processing on it using various openCV functions. Now, I want to display this image as texture using openGL. For this purpose, how to perform a conversion between a cv::Mat array to a Glubyte array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the data type in your `IplImage / cv::Mat`.
If it is of type CV_8U, then the pixel format is already correct and you just need:

1. ensure that your OpenCV data has a correct color format with respect to your OpenGL context (OpenCV commomnly uses BGR color channel ordering instead of RGB)
2. if your original image has some orientation, then you need to flip it vertically using `cvFlip() / cv::flip()`. The rational behind is that OpenCV has the origine of the coordinate frame in the top left corner (y-axis going down) while OpenGL applications usually have the origin in the bottom (y-axis going up)
3. use the `data` pointer field of `IplImage / cv::Mat` to get access to the pixel data and load it into OpenGL.

If your image data is in another format than CV_8U, then you need to convert it to this pixel format first using the function `cvConvertScale() / cv::Mat::convertTo()`.

Comment: And I found the following link very useful. It shows a code snippet on how to do it. It is the same as sansuiso says.http://carldukeprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/converting-iplimage-to-opengl-texture/